# xcode 4 vs xcode 3 search behavior

Tags: xcode, search, xcode4, find, behavior

In xcode 3, when I would do a find in a file it would locate the matching string in the file, but when I deleted it from the searchbox the cursor would return to the original location.

In xcode 4, it finds the string, but if I delete it, the cursor does not move back.

It's a small thing, but I much prefered the xcode 3 behavior. Is there a setting for this some place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Feel free to file an enhancement request at bugreport.apple.com, for this and any other features where you find that Xcode 4 is a step backwards from Xcode 3.